# What problems could I encounter by not using FQDN's in my closed network?

Tags: domain-name-system, fqdn

I'm setting up a closed network (i.e. no connections outside it) and I have been thinking of setting up servers and services without FQDN's because it would much more convenient to connect to a service that way.

Services that will be offered as planned atm:

- Gitorious,
- Redmine,
- Hudson,
- Open Embedded and OBS,
- DHCP,
- DNS,
- MTA (postfix probably),
- Open LDAP,
- SIP server (asterisk).

There won't be more than one server to start with (Ubuntu 10.04). I might set some virtual machines up later on that same server and of course I might need to add more servers later.

So are there any problems in naming the addresses e.g. "redmine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use FQDN's and set your DHCP server to provide an appropriate DNS search suffix?

Comment: Newbie alert: I could do that, didn't know it was possible. I have never set up a DNS or DHCP server (or Open LDAP for that matter)...

Comment: Ah, righto — since you're a newbie another thing you may not have considered is naming your machines independently of the services they run and then using a CNAME to provide a friendly name for each service. Doing this gives you a bit of flexibility as your infrastructure needs change.

Comment: Well, that I was going to do, but indirectly. The server itself will be names something and the services are named after the service they provide. I planned this just for convenience, though, but I don't mind the flexibility!